# How to flush EOF and enable scanf to get new input without starting over the program in C

Tags: c

There are a lot of handling EOF answers, but their solutions are to break while loop and stop the program when see EOF. But what i want is that user input EOF (control + D), my program can flush it and ask user to input again.

Comment: The problem is that the input may be coming from a file, and not from a user.

Comment: please write a repo case or short code to explain your problem better.

Comment: You can use `read`, which is much low level, but lets you manage the input as you want.